# Как получить роли пользователя без запроса в базу данных

Tags: авторизация, asp.net-core, jwt

У меня есть проект ASP.NET Core 2.0 который использует JWT для авторизции.

Вот так он собирается:

```
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
claims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email));
claims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));

var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
foreach(var role in roles)
{
     claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
}
```

Далее на основе ролей должна работать система авторизации.

Как я понимаю одна из сильных сторон JWT в данном случае ещё и в том, что информацию по пользователю, в том числе и его роли не надо вытаскивать из базы данных, а она получается путём расшифровки JWT токена.

Если я напишу

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Moderator")]
 public MaterialViewModel GetMaterial(int i)
```

То всё работает как ожидается, пользователи без роли Moderator выполнить этот запрос не могут.

А как я могу узнать роли пользователя не залазя в базу данных? Используя JWT токен.

Я могу получить все роли пользователся таким образом:

```
_userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

Но как я понимаю (возможно ошибаюсь) что тут идёт запрос в базу данных.

Но по идее, информация о ролях уже есть в токене, как её теперь получить?

У меня JWT токен передаётся через header, конечно я могу его получить в `request.headers` и вручную расшифровать, но ведь система ASP.NET Core уже делает это когда проверяет атрибут `[Authorize(Roles = "Moderator")]`. Значит я могу где-то его взять уже расшифрованным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл такой способ:

`this.User.Claims` содержит все клеймы из JWT. Все клеймы с ключём

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
```

задают роль.

Не знаю насколько этот способ оптимальный, и почему сразу нету такого `User.GetRoles()`